# Proving that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\log(2)t))Z(t)^2}{t^2+\frac{1}{4}}~dt=\pi \log(2)$ where $Z(t)$ is the Riemann-Siegel Z-function.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, zeta-functions

While looking at articles relevant to the Riemann Hypothesis, I've seen that the [Riemann-Siegel Z-function $Z(t)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_function) is frequently used to study the Riemann zeta function along the critical line. Therefore, I decided to go on the [Wolfram Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/) site, and look up some interesting properties of that function. One of them I especially found interesting was this one ([Formula 10.04.21.0001.01](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.04.21.0001.01)):

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\log(2)t))Z(t)^2}{t^2+\frac{1}{4}}~dt=\pi \log(2) \tag{1}$$
However, the site does not provide a proof of this result. Therefore, this leads me to my current question:

> **Question:** How can we prove $(1)$?

---

In case one does not know the definition of $Z(t)$, it can be defined as:
$$Z(t)=e^{i\theta(t)}\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right),$$
where $\theta(\cdot )$ and $\zeta(\cdot )$ are the [Riemann-Siegel Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function) and [Riemann Zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) functions respectively. One definition of $\theta(t)$ is:
$$\theta(t) = \arg \left(\Gamma\left(\frac{2it+1}{4}\right)\right)- \frac{\log \pi}{2} t,$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot )$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

---

My first thought was to use the fact that the integrand is even, then consider a contour $C$ going along the real line from $-a$ to $a$ then going counter-clockwise along a semicircle centered at $0$ going from $a$ to $-a$.
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\log(2)t))Z(t)^2}{t^2+\frac{1}{4}}~dt=\frac{1}{2}\cdot PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\log(2)t))Z(t)^2}{t^2+\frac{1}{4}}~dt \tag{2}$$
Hence, we must consider:
$$\lim_{a \to \infty}\int_{C} f(z)~dz=\lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\int_{-a}^a f(z)~dz+\int_{\text{arc}} f(z)~dz\right),$$
where $f(z)=\dfrac{(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\log(2)z))Z(z)^2}{z^2+\frac{1}{4}}$. I found two poles at $z=\pm \frac{i}{2}$, but only $z=\frac{i}{2}$ is bounded by $C$. The residue at that point can be evaluated easily since we know it is a simple pole:
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\frac{i}{2}} \dfrac{(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\log(2)z))Z(z)^2}{z^2+\frac{1}{4}}=\lim_{z\to \frac{i}{2}} \frac{(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\log(2)z))Z(z)^2}{z+\frac{i}{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}i\log(2)$$
I evaluated the above limit, then confirmed it using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bz+to+i%2F2%7D+((3-sqrt(8)*cos(log(2)*z))*RiemannSiegelZ%5Bz%5D%5E2)%2F(z%2Bi%2F2)).
Multiplying by $2\pi i$ gives $\pi \log(2)$. However, notice that my answer seems to be off by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ due to equation $(2)$. Hence, I suspect that either $\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} \int_{\text{arc}}f(z)~dz\neq 0$ is the issue here, or that I missed one of the conditions necessary to apply the residue theorem.

---

**Note:** An answer to my question may consist of both real and complex methods.

Comment: The analytic continuation of $Z(t)^2$ is obtained from $$\vartheta(z) = \frac{\log \Gamma(\frac{1/2+iz}{2})- \log \Gamma(\frac{1/2-iz}{2})}{2i}- \frac{\log \pi}{2} z, \qquad Z(z)^2 = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1/2+iz}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1/2-iz}{2})}\pi^{-iz}\zeta(1/2+iz)^2$$

Comment: @reuns Thank you, yes I was reading your comment and I was trying to use it.

Comment: The first thing to do is proving the integral converges. Why should it do ?

Comment: @reuns Please give me a moment to think about that.